# user logged in within time frame

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm trying to figure out how to find a user that has been logged on within a time-frame?

Case:
Table of login data example

```
user,time_from,time_to
user1,19:10,19:20
user2,10:00,22:00
user3,18:00,18:59
```

I want to get if user1 and user2 have been online between 19:00 and 20:00 and user3 has not.

In this case data is stored in mysql, and am using php to output data.

Suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SQL statements? PHP loops? Anything? Please let us know with some code. Hey also, what format is the table data fields? DATETIME, INT, what?

Answer (score 0):

To find all users logged on in a specific time period, you need to check that `time_from` is less than the end of the period, *and* `time_to` is greater than the beginning.

A simple example using PDO:

```
$sql = 'SELECT user FROM login_data WHERE time_from <= ? AND time_to >= ? GROUP BY user';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$end_time, $start_time]);
$users = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This won't get you which users were *not* logged on in the specified time period, but you could theoretically join the results to your user table to find that.

Comment: I am aware of you suggested solution. This would sadly not include user2 as stated in example. It is easy enough to find who has come online. It gets difficult trying to include users that are online withing the time-frame.

Comment: This absolutely would include user2. 10:00 < 20:00 and 22:00 > 19:00.